# How to disable the shift+anykey combinations in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to write a directive to allow only numbers along with a single decimal value. But the shift key when pressed with numbers is showing up special characters.

Please suggest a way without the use of regex as i donot want to aloow the user to type in other characters

```
setTargetPage.directive('numPercent', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function (scope, element, attr, ctrl) {
            var keyCode = [8, 9, 37, 39, 46, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 96, 97, 98, 99, 100, 101, 102, 103, 104, 105, 110, 190];
            element.bind("keydown", function (event) {
                if ($.inArray(event.which, keyCode) == -1) {
                    event.preventDefault();
                }
                else {
                    if ((event.which == 110 || event.which == 190) && element.val().indexOf('.') > -1) {
                        event.preventDefault();
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is event.shiftKey (pure JS no particular need to AngularJS) that is true when Shift is pressed.